# Isotope.js display items staked in a column after loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope

Good evening,
I've got a problem with my layout built with isotope.js. I added the script to my website to sort a section of some jobs that my company did. So far so good. I made a little bit of customization, and I was able to make it work, but when it loads at the very beginning of the animation, it displays my item stacked in a pile, for a fraction of a second.

Here's my code:

LINK:

http://larchedigital.com/the-work/

HTML:

```
<div class="portfolioFilter">
    <a href="#" data-filter="*" class="current">All Categories</a>
    <a href="#" data-filter=".web">Web Design &amp; Development</a>
    <a href="#" data-filter=".branding">Branding</a>
    <a href="#" data-filter=".logo">Logo Refresh</a>
    <a href="#" data-filter=".packaging">Packaging Design</a>
    <a href="#" data-filter=".videography">Videography</a>
    <a href="#" data-filter=".photo">Photography</a>
</div>

<div class="portfolioContainer">
    <div class="web packaging logo social-ads branding">
        blablabla
    <div>
    <div class="videography photo">
    </div>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    var $container = $('.portfolioContainer');
    $container.isotope({
        filter: '*',
        animationOptions: {
            duration: 750,
            easing: 'linear',
            queue: false
        },
    layoutMode: 'masonry',
    masonry: { 
        isFitWidth: true 
    }
    });

    $('.portfolioFilter a').click(function(){
        $('.portfolioFilter .current').removeClass('current');
        $(this).addClass('current');

        var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
        $container.isotope({
            filter: selector,
            animationOptions: {
                duration: 750,
                easing: 'linear',
                queue: false
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

As you can notice, right after it loads, for a fraction of a second my divs are stacked in a column, and only after they are displayed in a row.

Any thought about what I did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

*«The load event is fired when a resource and its dependent resources have finished loading.»* [Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/load)

So just replace `$(window).load(function(){` by `$(document).ready(function(){` and Isotope will be instanciated even if the images haven't finished loading.

**EDIT**

The problem really is that Isotope is instanciated after all image have loaded.

So a walk around would be to set the `opacity` of the container to 0...
And once all images are loaded and Isotope is instanciated, set the `opacity` to 1.

In CSS:

```
.portfolioContainer{
    opacity:0;
}
```

In JS, after the closing backet of `$container.isotope({`:

```
$(".portfolioContainer").css({"opacity":1});
```

Comment: The document.ready function doesn't work in this case. My code was setup in that way at first, but with this method, the divs overlap each other.